# What is the use of MCMC techniques in this context?

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

Currently I'm learning about MCMC techniques. .

**Exercise**

A researcher wants to sample $\theta$ from a discrete distribution with density function
$$
f(\theta)= \begin{cases}p=1 / 6 & \theta=0 |\\ p=1 / 2 & \theta=1 |\\ p= 1 / 3 & \theta=2\end{cases}
$$
He is only able to sample from the discrete distribution
$$
g(\theta)= \begin{cases}p=1 / 3 & \theta=0 |\ p=1 / 3 & \theta=1 |\ p= 1 / 3 & \theta=2\end{cases}
To sample $\theta$ from $f(\theta)$ hp uses a Metropolis-Hastings sampler. He samples from the candidate density $g(\theta)$ to obtain draws from the target density $f(\theta)$.

Let $\theta^{(m)}$ denote the $m$ th draw of the Metropolis-Hastings sampler. After convergence of the sampler, it holds that if $\theta^{(m)}$ is a draw of $f(\theta)$ then $\theta^{(m+1)}$ will also be a draw of $f(\theta)$. Use the computed transition probability matrix to show that this is indeed the case for this sampler.

**Answer**

[image]

**Question**

I understand all calculus behind this. I suppose that a entry in the transition matrix is the probability that you go from state $i$ in the parameter space to state $j$. My question is regarding the concept.

- What is the meaning behind multiplying the pdf of the target function with the transition matrix?
- What does this actually mean?: "After convergence of the sampler, it holds that if $\theta^{(m)}$ is a draw of $f(\theta)$ then $\theta^{(m+1)}$ will also be a draw of $f(\theta)$."